# Move a zero from a list to the end and leave the non-zero as is

Tags: python, function, loops

Problem to solve for: Write an algorithm that takes an array and moves all of the zeros to the end, preserving the order of the other elements.

Solution tested:

```
array = ["a",0,0,"b","c","d",0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]
newlist=[]
number_of_zero=0
for i in array:
    if i==0:
        number_of_zero+=1
    if i!=0:
        newlist.append(i)
        print(newlist)
        
for i in range(number_of_zero):
    newlist.append(0)

print(newlist)
```

The solution worked great but however when I migrate all this over to a function, my tests fail and I'm not sure why since the solution tested 100% using jupyter notebook

Solution implemented:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    newlist=[]
    count = 0
    for i in array:
        if i==0: #Everytime a zero is encountered, the count of zero is increased
            count+=1
        if i!=0:
            newlist.append(i) #if the value encountered while looping is not zero, append it to the new array
            #print(newlist)
        
    for i in range(count):
        newlist.append(0) #This loop will append zero times it got counted

    return newlist
```

Can someone suggest me why is my code failing when wrapped into a function? Do not see anything wrong with my logic.

Comment: You don't `return newlist` in your function

Comment: Good catch. However after adding that it still fails two tests: Testcase1)['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      TestCase2) [1, None, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0 ] . What changes can I make to avoid this? Jupyter runs the code fine with the two failed testcases

Comment: where did you add the `return` statement? inside `for` loop or outside? Please update the code in question.

Comment: I updated my code. It's inside the function which shouldnt be an issue

Comment: It returns `[1, None, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]` also add expected output?

Comment: Sorry Testcase#2 which failed is [0,1,None,2,False,1,0] and Testcase#1: ["a",0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9]

Comment: Actual output in Jupyter for Testcase#2 is [1, None, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]. Expected output:[1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: Looks like my code is failing when I have a false in there

Comment: yes, False == 0 is True in python

Comment: What changes can I make on my current code to prevent that issue? Will adding an or condition in my if statement help?

Comment: You need to change your logic. False == 0 evaluates to True. Try "if i is 0"... else

Comment: That did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def move_zeros(array):
    newlist=[]
    zerolist = []
    for i in array:
        # False == 0 will evaluate to True (but False should stay in place), ignore boolean types
        # not isinstance(i, bool) means anything other than True or False
        # True and False (like everything else) are objects in python
        if not isinstance(i, bool):
            # at this point, we can use ==, which will only evaluate to True if an int or float is zero
            if i == 0:
                # add the zero, but maintain the type (int or float)
                zerolist.append(i)
                # go to the next iteration
                continue
        # if the continue statement wasn't executed, everything else will be added here
        newlist.append(i)
    # append the zero list (with the same types) to the non-zero list
    return newlist + zerolist
```

Comment: [9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9] that logic would fail this test case then. Now i have 9 out of 10 test cases which passed

Comment: Do you need to move floating point zeros to the end as floats, or can they all be int zeros?

Comment: Well technically yes, if its a float that should be treated as zero too but its not a test case required to pass so i'm not worried about that

Comment: If you need to maintain the type of zero (float / int), you should keep a separate list and add it to the end. See my edit above.

Comment: if not isinstance(i, bool): What does this mean? Is that negate of True which is False. Can you comment your code like I did on myne!

Comment: not isinstance(i, bool) will skip over python object boolean values True and False (they will get added like every other non-zero item). Edited my code with comments.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a codewars problem I remember solving some time ago. The trick to this problem is accounting for the "truthiness" of 1's and 0's or the "numberness" of `True` and `False`.

My solution is you append all the values that are not equal to 0 or are bool values (to capture the `False` values) using the `isinstance()` function

then you can calculate the difference in length of your original list against your "non zero" list. Then take that difference and append zeros to it.

```
def move_zeros(array):
    no_zeroes = [x for x in array if x != 0 or isinstance(x, bool)]

    solution = no_zeroes + (len(array) - len(no_zeroes))*[0]

    return solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip the zeroes and add them all in one go afterwards by counting the difference in length

```
arr = ["a",0,0,"b","c","d",0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]

def move_zeros(array):
    nz = [e for e in arr if e is not 0]
    return nz+[0]*(len(arr)-len(nz))

print(move_zeros(arr))
```

produces

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Your not wrong but as a beginner find it a bit challenging to understand your result portion

Comment: This is a good solution, except I believe it will fail on float values. @Pynchia is right. List comprehensions may be confusing at first, but they are very useful and in fact I think are more readable to non-beginners. List comprehensions communicate very clearly to a reader that a list is being generated without all the rest of the fluff.

Comment: You cannot use python without studying lists and list comprehensions. My solution creates a new list as a result. Note: the input is a list, not an array. The latter is a sequence of elements of the same type. Yours clearly isn't

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple

```
newlist = sorted(array, key=(lambda x: x is 0))
```

If you don't mind mutating the original list you can do

```
array.sort(key=(lambda x: x is 0))
```

Note that normally we would test equality with `==` rather than `is`, but using `is` allows us to differentiate `0` from `False`.  This counts on the fact that the CPython implementation preallocates integers from -5 to 256. Unfortunately, that means the behavior of `0 is 0` is implementation defined.  You can still count on it though, because there is not a major Python implementation that does not act like CPython in this regard (Cython, PyPy, IronPython, Jython).